# how to make objects to be placed in the right place and automatically resized depending on the screen size?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIj7z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHKt1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGm55.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60n9D.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwJH.png)

I want to those three button to be placed in the right place on all decvice screen whether it be small screen size or big screen size. I tried applying constraints to top,bottom,leading and trailing on iPhone Xs and it looks fine because i'm working on the device but when i view it as on iPhone 4s, it doesn't look like what i'm expecting. How do i make it look the same on even small screen size? Like iPhone 4s.

And i want all objects(my buttons) to be resized automatically depending on the screen size. When i put on one view, it resizes automatically depending on the screen size (as you can see from the pictures) but when i put three buttons, they don't resize depending on the screen size.

Please anybody help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are way over-determined, which is a recipe for disaster.

Just to take a simple example (from your two first screen shots): you design your constraints for an XSMax and you pin the buttons to the top, to each other, and to the bottom. So what's supposed to happen when we run on a 4s which is much shorter? All those constraints cannot simultaneously be true! And that is exactly what Xcode is telling you.

> How do i make it look the same on even small screen size

What does "the same" even mean on a smaller screen size? As I just said, it cannot mean this exact distance from the top and this exact distance from the bottom; there isn't room. That question is exactly what *you* have to think about. Do you want the buttons always the same distance from the top? Or from the bottom? (You cannot have both, that's what Xcode and I are telling you.) Or maybe you want them always in the middle? What? Decide and design accordingly.